# Spring Declarative transaction management failed with jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

I am using Spring 3.2.2 version,

I have a issue when I am using @Transactional with jdbc template,

My XML configuration is below:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<bean id="reportTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="reportDataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" order="0"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="reportTransactionManager" order="1"/>
```

Code  :

```
@Transactional(value = "reportTransactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ReportResponse deleteAndSave(input) throws ReportServiceException {

        service1.saveData(input);
        service2.saveData(input);
        service3.saveData(input);
        service4.saveData(input);
        service5.saveData(input);
        service6.saveData(input);
        service7.saveData(input);



    } catch (Exception exception) {
        _LOGGER.debug("Caught exception all KPI changes should be reverted back for scenario id {}", scenarioId);
        _LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(exception));
        throw new ReportServiceException(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }
    return reportResponse;
}
```

So issues is whenever any service fails everthing should roll back but in my case if suppose service7 failed all services are roll backed except one service i.e service4 only,

I thought may be transaction is not propagating to service4 api, then I tested using

```
   TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName();
   TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive();
   TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
   TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
```

Its returning me the transaction and its details properly, but still not rollbacking

I surprised that why only that service api is failed to rollback , Can any one please suggest me on this.

Note : Apart from deleteAndSave api in root method, no other services/ repository classes does not have any @transaction becoz by default spring will propagate.
I dont have anyissue with hibernate transactionManager bcoz these services involved with reportTransactionManager manager only.

Comment: You show you use 2 different transaction managers, but don't say how they are related to you different services. Which use `sessionFactory` an which use `reportDataSource` ?

Comment: Hiberante transaction manager , I am using in different services, But my issue with reportTransactionManager only

Comment: I ask my question differently do the different services only deal with `reportDataSource` and never with `sessionFactory` ?

Comment: I got reason, There is no problem with transaction manger, the service which is failing actually dealing with Mysql MyISAM engine so MyISAM does not support transactions so I changed DB engine to InnoDB then its working fine. Sorry for troubling you guys !!